# XML Child elements, how do they work?

Tags: c#, xml, children, element

So, I'm trying to figgure out how to create child elements for a root element.

---

### Project background:

I'm creating an app that will calculate the cheapest travel cost between cities in a pc-game.

In the game there is about 13 cities in which you can travel in between for a fee.

Now the fee is always the same but varies from city to city. In some cases it's cheaper to travel via another city instead of going one-way straight to your destination. Sometimes there is no connection at all between two cities which forces you to take another route.

*Let's say* we're in **CITY A** and want to go to **CITY B**.
If there is no straight connection between **A** and **B** we have to take a different route.

**CITY C** has connection to both **A** and **B** so this is an option but what if **CITY D** also has connection to **A** and **B** but to a cheaper price?

I hope you see where I'm getting at. Now let's go to creating the XML-document.

```
 private void exportXMLfileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();



            #region text
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("city.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            writer.Indentation = 2;

            writer.WriteStartElement("Table");
            createNode("CITY A", writer); //THE NAME OF A CITY
            createElement("CITY C", 120, writer); // "CITY A" HAS CONNECTIONS TO THEESE CITIES. (ELEMENTS)
            createElement("CITY D", 60, writer);

            createNode("CITY B", writer); //CITY NAME
            createElement("CITY C", 130, writer); //CITY CONNECTIONS
            createElement("CITY D", 70, writer);

            createNode("CITY C", writer); //CITY NAME
            createElement("CITY A", 120, writer); //CITY CONNECTIONS
            createElement("CITY B", 130, writer);

            createNode("CITY D", writer);//CITY NAME
            createElement("CITY A", 60, writer); //CITY CONNECTIONS
            createElement("CITY B", 70, writer);



            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Close();
            #endregion

        }

        private void createNode(string mainCity, XmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("BaseCity");
            writer.WriteStartAttribute("Name");
            writer.WriteString(mainCity);
            writer.WriteEndAttribute();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        private void createElement(string cityName, int price, XmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("City");
            writer.WriteStartAttribute("Name");
            writer.WriteString(cityName);
            writer.WriteStartElement("Price");
            writer.WriteString(price.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();

        }
    }
```

This is the output:
No structure....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

-<Table>    
<BaseCity Name="CITY A"/>
-<City Name="CITY C">    
<Price>120</Price>    
</City>   
-<City Name="CITY D">    
<Price>60</Price>    
</City>

<BaseCity Name="CITY B"/>    
-<City Name="CITY C">    
<Price>130</Price>    
</City>  
-<City Name="CITY D">    
<Price>70</Price>    
</City>

<BaseCity Name="CITY C"/>   
-<City Name="CITY A">    
<Price>120</Price>    
</City>        
-<City Name="CITY B">    
<Price>130</Price>    
</City>

<BaseCity Name="CITY D"/>    
-<City Name="CITY A">    
<Price>60</Price>    
</City>        
-<City Name="CITY B">    
<Price>70</Price>    
</City>   
</Table>
```

I want it to be like this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

    -<Table>    
    <BaseCity Name="CITY A"/>
        -<City Name="CITY C">    
        <Price>120</Price>    
        </City>   
        -<City Name="CITY D">    
        <Price>60</Price>    
        </City>

    <BaseCity Name="CITY B"/>    
        -<City Name="CITY C">    
        <Price>130</Price>    
        </City>  
        -<City Name="CITY D">    
        <Price>70</Price>    
        </City>
```

Comment: Do not use xml writers. Create an xml document, [save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2w98a50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it with [indentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: what's with the minus signs?

Comment: @sharonbn they appear in the XML-document as clickable and collapses the element.

Comment: so this is a feature of the viewer/editor that you use. its not part of the document itself, you do realise that?

Comment: please add tag for programming language that you use

Comment: @sharonbn You made me realize it :) Added C# tag aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with LINQ to XML:

```
            XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("Cities",
            new XElement("AbDendriel",
                new XElement("Carlin", "80"),
                    new XElement("Edron", "70"),
                    new XElement("Thais", "130"),
                    new XElement("Venore", "90"),
                    new XElement("Yalahar", "160")),
        new XElement("Ankrahmun",
                new XElement("Darashia", "100"),
                    new XElement("Edron", "160"),
                    new XElement("LibertyBay", "90"),
                    new XElement("PortHope", "80"),
                    new XElement("Venore", "90"),
                    new XElement("Yalahar", "160")),
        new XElement("Carlin",
                new XElement("AbDendriel", "80"),
                    new XElement("Edron", "110"),
                    new XElement("Svargrond", "110"),
                    new XElement("Thais", "110"),
                    new XElement("Venore", "130"),
                    new XElement("Yalahar", "160")),
        new XElement("Darashia",
                new XElement("Ankrahmun", "100"),
                    new XElement("LibertyBay", "200"),
                    new XElement("PortHope", "180"),
                    new XElement("Thais", "160"),
                    new XElement("Venore", "60"),
                    new XElement("Yalahar", "210")),
        new XElement("Edron",
                new XElement("AbDendriel", "70"),
                    new XElement("Ankrahmun", "160"),
                    new XElement("Carlin", "110"),
                    new XElement("LibertyBay", "170"),
                    new XElement("PortHope", "150"),
                    new XElement("Thais", "160"),
                    new XElement("Venore", "40")),
        new XElement("LibertyBay",
                new XElement("Ankrahmun", "90"),
                    new XElement("Darashia", "200"),
                    new XElement("Edron", "170"),
                    new XElement("PortHope", "50"),
                    new XElement("Thais", "180"),
                    new XElement("Venore", "180"),
                    new XElement("Yalahar", "275")),
        new XElement("PortHope",
                new XElement("Ankrahmun", "110"),
                    new XElement("Darashia", "180"),
                    new XElement("Edron", "150"),
                    new XElement("LibertyBay", "50"),
                    new XElement("Thais", "160"),
                    new XElement("Venore", "160"),
                    new XElement("Yalahar", "260")),
        new XElement("Roshamuul",
                new XElement("Thais", "210")),
        new XElement("Oramond",
                new XElement("Edron", "110"),
                    new XElement("PortHope", "200"),
                    new XElement("Thais", "150"),
                    new XElement("Venore", "130")),
        new XElement("Svargrond",
                new XElement("Carlin", "110"),
                    new XElement("Thais", "180"),
                    new XElement("Venore", "150")),
        new XElement("Thais",
                new XElement("AbDendriel", "130"),
                    new XElement("Carlin", "110"),
                    new XElement("Edron", "160"),
                    new XElement("LibertyBay", "180"),
                    new XElement("PortHope", "160"),
                    new XElement("Roshamuul", "210"),
                    new XElement("Oramond", "150"),
                    new XElement("Svargrond", "180"),
                    new XElement("Venore", "170"),
                    new XElement("Yalahar", "200")),
        new XElement("Venore",
                new XElement("AbDendriel", "90"),
                    new XElement("Ankrahmun", "150"),
                    new XElement("Carlin", "130"),
                    new XElement("Darashia", "60"),
                    new XElement("Edron", "40"),
                    new XElement("LibertyBay", "180"),
                    new XElement("PortHope", "160"),
                    new XElement("Svargrond", "150"),
                    new XElement("Thais", "170"),
                    new XElement("Yalahar", "185")),
        new XElement("Yalahar",
                new XElement("AbDendriel", "160"),
                    new XElement("Ankrahmun", "230"),
                    new XElement("Carlin", "185"),
                    new XElement("Darashia", "210"),
                    new XElement("LibertyBay", "275"),
                    new XElement("PortHope", "260"),
                    new XElement("Thais", "210"),
                    new XElement("Venore", "185"))));
        doc.Save("city.xml");
```

Output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Cities>        
<AbDendriel>
    <Carlin>80</Carlin>
    <Edron>70</Edron>
    <Thais>130</Thais>
    <Venore>90</Venore>
    <Yalahar>160</Yalahar>    
</AbDendriel>

<Ankrahmun>    
    <Darashia>100</Darashia>    
    <Edron>160</Edron>    
    <LibertyBay>90</LibertyBay>
    <PortHope>80</PortHope>
    <Venore>90</Venore>
    <Yalahar>160</Yalahar>
</Ankrahmun>

<Carlin>
    <AbDendriel>80</AbDendriel>
    <Edron>110</Edron>
    <Svargrond>110</Svargrond>
    <Thais>110</Thais>
    <Venore>130</Venore>
    <Yalahar>160</Yalahar>    
</Carlin>

<Darashia>
    <Ankrahmun>100</Ankrahmun>
    <LibertyBay>200</LibertyBay>
    <PortHope>180</PortHope>
    <Thais>160</Thais>
    <Venore>60</Venore>
    <Yalahar>210</Yalahar>
</Darashia>

<Edron>
    <AbDendriel>70</AbDendriel>
    <Ankrahmun>160</Ankrahmun>
    <Carlin>110</Carlin>
    <LibertyBay>170</LibertyBay>
    <PortHope>150</PortHope>
    <Thais>160</Thais>
    <Venore>40</Venore>
</Edron>

<LibertyBay>
    <Ankrahmun>90</Ankrahmun>
    <Darashia>200</Darashia>
    <Edron>170</Edron>
    <PortHope>50</PortHope>
    <Thais>180</Thais>
    <Venore>180</Venore>
    <Yalahar>275</Yalahar>    
</LibertyBay>

<PortHope>
    <Ankrahmun>110</Ankrahmun>
    <Darashia>180</Darashia>
    <Edron>150</Edron>
    <LibertyBay>50</LibertyBay>
    <Thais>160</Thais>
    <Venore>160</Venore>
    <Yalahar>260</Yalahar>    
</PortHope>

<Roshamuul>
    <Thais>210</Thais>
</Roshamuul>

<Oramond>
    <Edron>110</Edron>
    <PortHope>200</PortHope>
    <Thais>150</Thais>
    <Venore>130</Venore>
</Oramond>

<Svargrond>
    <Carlin>110</Carlin>
    <Thais>180</Thais>
    <Venore>150</Venore>
</Svargrond>

<Thais>
   <AbDendriel>130</AbDendriel>
   <Carlin>110</Carlin>
   <Edron>160</Edron>
   <LibertyBay>180</LibertyBay>
   <PortHope>160</PortHope>
   <Roshamuul>210</Roshamuul>
   <Oramond>150</Oramond>
   <Svargrond>180</Svargrond>
   <Venore>170</Venore>
   <Yalahar>200</Yalahar>
</Thais>

<Venore>
    <AbDendriel>90</AbDendriel>
    <Ankrahmun>150</Ankrahmun>
    <Carlin>130</Carlin>
    <Darashia>60</Darashia>
    <Edron>40</Edron>
    <LibertyBay>180</LibertyBay>
    <PortHope>160</PortHope>
    <Svargrond>150</Svargrond>
    <Thais>170</Thais>
    <Yalahar>185</Yalahar>
</Venore>

<Yalahar>
    <AbDendriel>160</AbDendriel>
    <Ankrahmun>230</Ankrahmun>
    <Carlin>185</Carlin>
    <Darashia>210</Darashia>
    <LibertyBay>275</LibertyBay>
    <PortHope>260</PortHope>
    <Thais>210</Thais>
    <Venore>185</Venore>
</Yalahar>
</Cities>
```